# TortoiseSVN command line to diff 2 svn files with different names and version

Tags: svn, cmd, tortoisesvn, diff

I created a small program in C# to diff a big amount of files from svn with a user friendly window. You just give the svn Version of the original file and of the new version and a list of files to diff with full path. What happens behind is just a cmd call like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:diff /ignoreprops /startrev:3 /endrev:770 /path:"x:\myPath\myFile.c"
```

see [Automating TortoiseSVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html)

But now I would like to have the possibility to diff 2 svn files with different name. The content is pretty much the same but the name was slightly changed, something like from myFile.c to my_File.c. I know it looks something like:

```
"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:diff /ignoreprops /path:"x:\myPath\myFile.c" /path2:"x:\myPath\my_File.c"
```

but I cannot figure out how to add svn version to it, I have tried this without success:

```
"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:diff /ignoreprops /startrev:3 /endrev:770 /path:"x:\myPath\myFile.c" /path2:"x:\myPath\my_File.c"
```

Does anyone know if it is possible or maybe anotherway to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `showcompare` command:

```
"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe"
    /command:showcompare
    /ignoreprops
    /url1:"x:\myPath\myFile.c"
    /url2:"x:\myPath\my_File.c"
    /revision1:3
    /revision2:770
```

Comment: I guess since my checked out version is 770, the file url1:"x:\myPath\myFile.c" does not exist locally anymore, I only  have url2:"x:\myPath\my_File.c". When running the command I get the following error: 

_Subversion reported an error:
The node "x:\myPath\myFile.c" was not found_

Comment: If you don't have myFile.c locally, then you have to use url to the file that was available at revision 3. Something like `url1:"http://your-svn/repository/trunk/myFile.c"`

Comment: nice! it works now with the `"http://your-svn/repository...` path. Thanks